# Scrape all replies from YouTube comments

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract all replies to all comments in an order from Youtube.
My can scrape all the comments but is unable to get the replies under them. I am having this error. I am on Linux.

```
Message: Element <paper-button id="more" class="style-scope ytd-expander"> could not be scrolled into view
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOzZDdXetUA')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 500);')

time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 3000);')

comments=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')

while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="more"]')
        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

time.sleep(10)

number_of_items=len(name)
for i in range (number_of_items):
    print(name[i].text + " : ")
    print(comments[i].text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you get this message when there is no more comments and you reached the end?

Comment: no in the start before getting any comment or anyother thing. if i remove this while loop part. It just get all the comments but no reply.This error occurs from loop.

Comment: Well, at least in Chrome I don't see that "more" button and I would just scroll to the bottom of the page in the loop if I would have used Chrome for this. Could you try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you were pretty closed.  I added a few lines to what you already had.  Does this do what you want?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Utility/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOzZDdXetUA')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 500);')

time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(1, 3000);')

comments=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')

while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="more"]')
        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

time.sleep(10)

number_of_items=len(name)
for i in range (number_of_items):
    print(name[i].text + " : ")
    print(comments[i].text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This message comes                         
.Message: Element <paper-button id="more" class="style-scope ytd-expander"> could not be scrolled into view